# árvore de utilizadores com pontos e perfil em C#

Tags: c#, array

Tenho uma listagem de utilizadores em que cada um tem um patrocinador (patrocinador é também um utilizador). Cada utilizador tem pontos e é de um tipo. Pretendo saber qual o ramo da árvore que tem maior numero de pontos e, para cada ramos saber quantos tipos iguais tenho.
Suponham que tenho a árvore:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado seria:
Para o número de Pontos de cada ramo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e para a o número de tipos iguais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a melhor maneira de conseguir isto?
Criei uma função que percorre toda a arvore e num array coloca os pontos e noutro array coloca os tipos. De qualquer forma, está a dar erro. Tenho andado às voltas mas estou a precisar de ajuda.
A função que criei é:

```
   //
    // FUNÇÃO TreeBranchPath
    int[] TotalPontosRamo = new int[1];
    int[,] FolhaInfoPontos = new int[6, 6];
    int[,] FolhaInfoPatamar = new int[6, 6];
    int CountRamos = 1;
    int CountFilhos = 0;

    private void TreeBranchPath(int idusr, int usrpnts, int usrpata, int ramo, int filho, bool FirstInteract)
    {

        FolhaInfoPontos[ramo, filho] = usrpnts;
        FolhaInfoPatamar[ramo, filho] = usrpata;

        if (FirstInteract)
        {
            ramo = ramo + 1;
        }



        /* Inicio - Verifica se tem descendentes - afilhados */
        Session["ConfDados"] = Session["ConfDados"] + "Verifica se o User " + idusr + " tem descendentes<br>";
        var AfilhadosList = (from af in db.NRV_USERS
                                where af.idpatrocinador == idusr
                                select af).ToList();

        if (AfilhadosList.Count() != 0)
        {


            foreach (var descid in AfilhadosList)
            {

                CountFilhos = CountFilhos + 1;

                /* Inicio - Quantos Pontos o User tem */
                var UserPoints = (from pnt in db.NRV_USERPONTOS
                                    where pnt.iduser == descid.id_user && pnt.usrpntact == true
                                    select pnt).FirstOrDefault();

                int TotalUserPoints = UserPoints.pontosgrupo + UserPoints.pontosproprios;

                Session["ConfDados"] = Session["ConfDados"] + "O User " + descid.id_user + " tem  " + TotalUserPoints + " pontos (" + UserPoints.pontosgrupo + " + " + UserPoints.pontosproprios + ")<br>";
                /* Fim - Quantos Pontos o User tem */


                /* Inicio - Em que Patamar o User está */
                var AuxUserPatamar = (from cp in db.NRV_USERPATAMAR
                                      where cp.iduser == descid.id_user
                                      select cp.idpatamax).FirstOrDefault();
                Session["ConfDados"] = Session["ConfDados"] + "O User " + descid.id_user + " está no Patamar Maximo " + AuxUserPatamar + "<br>";
                /* Fim - Em que Patamar o User está */


                //FolhaInfoPontos = ResizeArray(FolhaInfoPontos, ramo + 1, numfilho + 1);
                //FolhaInfoPatamar = ResizeArray(FolhaInfoPatamar, ramo + 1, numfilho + 1);

                TreeBranchPath(descid.id_user, TotalUserPoints, AuxUserPatamar, ramo, CountFilhos, false);

               // TotalPontosRamo[ramo] = TotalPontosRamo[ramo] + TotalUserPoints;


                ramo = ramo + 1;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            //ramo = ramo + 1;
            CountRamos = CountRamos + 1;
            CountFilhos = 0;
            Session["ConfDados"] = Session["ConfDados"] + "O User " + idusr + " do Ramo " + ramo + " não descendentes<br><br>";
        }



    }
```

Será que alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Coloquei os arrays com limite 6, mas a verdade é que não sei qual o limite. O array deve ser dinamico de forma a ir aumentando sempre o numero de ramos e de filhos.

Comment: Já está! Obrigado a todos pela ajuda e/ou dicas

Comment: Ricardo, parece pelos comentários que essa sua pergunta foi respondia, ou resolvida. Se for, considere *respondendo-a com sua solução final*, ou tem a opção de *remover a pergunta*.

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma classe que tenha as seguintes propriedades:

```
class DadosRamo {
  LinkedList<Filho> PontosDoRamo;
  int TotalDePontos = 0;
  Dictionary<Filho, int> contagemPorTipoDeFilho;
}
```

- `PontosDoRamo`: Conforme tu caminhas pela lista, tu deves armazenar os pontos nessa lista ligada.
- `TotalDePontos`: Some os pontos de cada filho aqui, no final terás o total.
- `ContagemPorTipoDeFilho`: Adicione o filho ao dicionario, caso já esteja lá, adicione 1 à contagem.

Ao final você deverá ter uma `List<DadosRamo>` com informações de todos os seus ramos.

Answer (score -2):

a pergunta parece pertinente e não sei até que ponto serei capaz de dar uma resposta adequada, mas se tivesse de abordar um problema desta natureza, preferia, talvez, usar uma arquitectura como MongoDB, talvez combinada com Ruby on Rails